# IF else statement inside select statement in sql

Tags: mysql, database, select, if-statement

how can i insert if else statement into select statement using mysql? Please help me. I'm new here..
I've tried using delimiter, but they have error..
 For example this statement:

```
SELECT c_id
  FROM customer
 WHERE city = 'AZ';

SELECT order_no,
       o_status 
  FROM order_status,
       customer
 WHERE order_status.c_id = customer.c_id;

UPDATE order_status 
   SET item_total=0
 WHERE o_status='waiting';
```

Comment: Why don't you describe what you want to do and why do you need an IF there so we can understand better your situation and guide you with the best solution to it?

Comment: i just want to know how to use if-else statement inside select statement.. despite any condition. can i use delimiter inside select statements?

Comment: [Yes, you can use, however in MySQL, there is no `IF/ELSE` there is `IF`, `IFNULL`, `NULLIF` and `CASE`. `CASE` would be the closest to `IF/ELSE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: You don't have any IF statements in your example. You just have three statements. Show what you've tried. Show the error. Show what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It would seem you have some programming background and are struggling to merge your programming view of the world with SQL. Please look at the answer Edi G. below, seems he may have read your intention, and translated in into SQL thinking for you. There is no obvious need to insert IF/ELSE into any of those 3 queries, but without stating it, you may be wanting to know how to usefully combine those parts.

Comment: I actualy want to know how to use delimiter and how to put if else statement inside delimiter? Can you teach me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
    UPDATE order_status 
       SET item_total=0
      FROM order_status os
INNER JOIN customer c
        ON c.c_id = os.c_id
     WHERE os.o_status='waiting' AND c.city = 'AZ'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
```

If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns expr2; otherwise it returns expr3. IF() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

```
mysql> SELECT IF(1>2,2,3);
        -> 3
mysql> SELECT IF(1<2,'yes','no');
        -> 'yes'
mysql> SELECT IF(STRCMP('test','test1'),'no','yes');
        -> 'no'
```

If only one of expr2 or expr3 is explicitly NULL, the result type of the IF() function is the type of the non-NULL expression.

The default return type of IF() (which may matter when it is stored into a temporary table) is calculated as follows.
Expression  Return Value

```
expr2 or expr3 returns a string string
expr2 or expr3 returns a floating-point value   floating-point
expr2 or expr3 returns an integer   integer
```

If expr2 and expr3 are both strings, the result is case sensitive if either string is case sensitive.